# Looking for N-Channel MOSFET with igss<10nA

Tags: mosfet

I'm looking for a surface mount mosfet with a gate leakage in the pA or very low nA range, so I can drive the gate from a very high impedance source.  Since most people don't care that much about igss of a mosfet, it's not a searchable parameter on Digikey, Mouser, etc.

I have found some mosfets with igss in the pA range, but they seem to be out of production.
However, that proves they can be made.  I was hoping somebody could point me towards a part.

Comment: 10,000 volt rating on VDS? 1,000 amp rating on Id? You are making virtually the same mistake you are complaining about LOL.

Comment: How much current (IDS) and voltage.  The 2n7000 lists a max leakage of 10nA.. though I suspect in practice it's much lower.

Comment: If you have a very high source impedance, how are you going to deal with the relatively high capacitance of a MOSFET gate? Most people use JFETs in such applications.

Comment: @Dave.  Thank you for that.  I have never used a JFET in decades of professional work, so did not know this was something they were good for.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I know little of Jfets, and you are suppose to operate them with a negative Vgs, but if they forward bias a bit don't they leak like sieves.. well or like forward biased diodes?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: Yes, if you forward bias them, they pass current. But in reverse bias, their leakage and capacitance are both generally much lower than most diodes.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold You can use a JFET as a low leakage diode..

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Thanks, I didn't know that.  (I assume it's the small area that helps keep the leakage low.)  Is the reverse bias voltage any better (higher) than Vbe in a bipolar transistor?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a **guaranteed** low leakage- you may have to look through a lot of datasheets.

CD4007 has a typical leakage of +/-10pA at 25°C

Note that most of the leakage in modern devices is the gate protection devices, not the gate itself. With a part like the 4007 you can connect the otherwise unused Vdd to double your anticipated common mode voltage to get approximate cancellation of the leakages.

3N170/171 is available in SMT package and has 10pA *maximum* gate leakage (at 25°C) but expect to pay dearly for that kind of testing.